# How to use function outside of its class

Tags: arrays, swift, function, class, search

I have the below class and I use a function match to search the string in both `SongTitle` and in `ESongTitle`.

```
class KeerthanaiArray: NSObject {
var SongTitle: String = String()
var SongLyrics: String = String()
var ESongTitle: String = String()

init(SongTitle: String, SongLyrics:String, ESongTitle: String) {
    self.SongTitle = SongTitle
    self.SongLyrics = SongLyrics
    self.ESongTitle = ESongTitle
}

func match(string:String) -> Bool {
    return SongTitle.containsString(string) || ESongTitle.containsString(string)
}
}
```

I was unable to use the function match outside of its class, so I tried using the below logic:

```
for keerthanaiArrayObject in keerthanaiArray {
        let searchr = (keerthanaiArrayObject.match(searchText.lowercaseString))}
```

But now I am unable to refer `searchr` outside of its for loop.  Please assist in referencing these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `searchr` to a var instead? As in, define it outside the for loop, then reassign it inside the for loop.

Something like this:

```
var searchr: Bool?

for keerthanaiArrayObject in keerthanaiArray {
    searchr = (keerthanaiArrayObject.match(searchText.lowercaseString))    
}
```

Also, side note: the name of your KeerthanaiArray is misleading. Your object should be a single item, not an array. I suggest you change the name to just Keerthanai, then when you need a list of Keerthanai objects, you can wrap them in an array.

Like this.

```
var keerthanaiArray = [keerthanaiObject1, keerthanaiObject2, keerthanaiObject3]
```

Comment: when I declared the searchr as Bool then my further code doesn't work.   I have the below code  self.searchResults = searchr.filter({(searchr) -> Bool in

Comment: Now it gives me the error message value of type 'Bool?' has no member 'filter'

Comment: Wait then your code doesn't make sense.

Your Match function returns a Boolean value right? Which you then assign to `searchr` in this line:
`let searchr = (keerthanaiArrayObject.match(searchText.lowercaseString))`

 So `searcher` is of type Bool and filter cannot be used on a bool values, only on arrays and maps.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in `self.searchResults = searchr.filter({(searchr) -> Bool in `?